# APIs Disappearing from Stackify and Reappears after Azure App Service restarts after a While

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, stackify

I have integrated my APIs hosted on Azure App Service with Stackify, and I'm facing an issue where the APIs are initially visible, and logs are coming in, but after some time, they disappear. When I manually restart the Azure App Service, they reappear. What could be causing this behavior, and how can I resolve it?